# Best practices of "securing" an API without login/password

Tags: api, rest, mobile, backend

I have a client app which can be identified with some UID. 
I have a backend service which the client app needs to call to retrieve some listings.
What would be the best practice to secure this backend service? I don't want to protect by login/password (because client should not be required to "login" to retrieve the listings), however, I'd not want anybody easily to call this backend API and retrieve those listings for their own purposes.
Think about the client as custom Flash client, or Mobile client, etc.
The communication is over HTTP REST.
Any ideas?

Thanks

**UPDATE: Sorry, forgot to mention -- without using SSL. Basically I am looking for some algorithm/strategy idea here. Thanks for suggestions!**

Comment: some kind of long random token that identify the user ?

Comment: What happened to the other answer? It had some really good links!

Comment: If you aren't using SSL, you will fail.  A bad guy can easily spy on the communication between server/client and do all sorts of bad things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general idea here is that you would use HTTPS with the client configured to sign their requests using a X.509 certificate that the API provider issued to them via some other secure method.  The server would have this certificate (or better yet a certificate that the client's certificate is a child of) as well and can verify that the incomming request was signed using it.  This is pretty standard for server-to-server communication.  It doesn't work if you're building an app for end users to run locally because a bad guy could easily extract this certificate from the client app and defeat the whole scheme

There are lots of technology-specific articles about how to configure this and you haven't specified what stack you're using but here's a generic article just to prove that I'm not making this stuff up :)  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-SSL_client_authentication/

Comment: that's a great solution if you have server-to-server communication if you can make sure your cert is safe

Comment: yeah, for server-client where you don't trust the client there's really nothing bulletproof... in that case, the best you can do is minimize the pain by hiding the certificate you use and implementing throttling on the server

Comment: if you'd go through the effort to have your own CA (Certificate Authority), you could give each individual client it's own cert -- this way the certs can be revoked individually in case they are compromised.. but that's probably way too complicated as a practical scenario

Answer (score 3):

Hi I think you could take a look at this article, it uses hmac authentication. http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/

Do you remember that hash can be used to guarantee integrity ?for example, if you hash a request,and the server receives the request and the hash diggest, the server will hash the request and compare both requests, server and client. If they match, you can be sure the request has not be modified in the transition.
If you have a private value(nobody should know it!), let's say, "hiworld" ( the values are actually guids or random values) and you use that value as parameter for the hash, you would get a special hash value. 
If you send the request along the hash special value, and the server (who knows the private value) hashes the request using that special value, and both hashs diggest match, the server can be sure that the request was not tampered, and that you were who send it.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at OAuth for the authorization, and the connection should always be HTTPS so the packets can't be easily sniffed.

To use this without authentication is pretty insecure, as anybody could attempt to impersonate a valid client. Having the connection HTTPS would only slow down a hacker.

See:

http://oauth.net

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

http://library.edgecase.com/securing-apis-using-rack-middleware  (for Rails  / Rack)

http://developers.sun.com/identity/reference/techart/restwebservices.html

http://www.slideshare.net/mohangk/securing-your-web-api-with-oauth

and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150207070814/http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/) might be interesting as well: (without OAuth).

Comment: No.  OAuth allows a user to give one system *authorization* to access that user's data from another system's services.  Authorization and authentication are very different beasts and, as you'll see on the oauth.net site you linked to, OAuth only attempts to solve authorization.  Also, this goes against the OP requirement to not make users enter credentials.

Comment: @RobertLevy: Though I agree that OAuth is used to solve authorization from the point of view of the user (User1 authorizes ServiceA to use data from ServiceB), surely a service can use OAuth for authentication? As in ServiceA asks User1 to authenticate him/herself using ServiceB (and at the same time gets permission to use identifying information from ServiceB). It is what many sites, SO included, now offer as a way of logging in without having to create seperate accounts all over the web.